# Window not opening after a successful build

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

When I'm building my electron app, the build has no error. Then, when I'm installing it, the window that is supposed to show up is not showing up. But if I launch the app with cmd: `myapp.exe` I can see in the logs that the app has perfectly started (the code is literally stopping before the `createWindow()`).

I know it's not coming from my code, because I've made a fresh install of Windows 10 (the app was perfectly launching itself after a build in my old Win 10 installation and I've made 0 changes in the code) and I'm pretty sure that is coming from that.

Comment: check out this link. it may help you https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the problem was not from my computer but from electron. I had electron version 11.2.1 and it was coming from that. So I downgraded to 11.1.0 and it's working fine.